# How to get the image classifiers result in this json info?

Tags: python, json, ibm-watson

I need to try and get to the answer `"class"` which is `"broke"` in this case. I have read the docs and I can't find anything that is helping me.

I have tried everything that I have found on the docs like `json.dumbs`, but I just can't get to this final answer.

```
import json


visual_recognition = VisualRecognitionV3(
                        version='---------',
                        iam_apikey='----------------------------',
                        url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api')
filename="aplogo.jpg"

with open('static/upload_folder/' + filename, 'rb') as images_file:
    classes = visual_recognition.classify(
                images_file, threshold='0.6',
                classifier_ids='DefaultCustomModel_-----').get_result()

json_data = (json.dumps(classes, indent=2))

print(json_data)
```

Result:

```
{
  "images": [
 {
  "classifiers": [
    {
      "classifier_id": "DefaultCustomModel_----",
      "name": "Default Custom Model",
      "classes": [
        {
          "class": "broke",
          "score": 0.919
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "image": "aplogo.jpg"
}
  ],
  "images_processed": 1,
  "custom_classes": 2
}
```

All I really need is the `"class": "broke", "score": 0.919I`. Have not found anything like this.

Comment: Try `print(json_data["images"][0]["classifiers"][0]["classes"])`. This references the JSON object (Python `dict`) which is the first item in the outer and the nested list.

Comment: I tried the above but I received the following error ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```

Comment: Sorry...try `print(classes["images"][0]["classifiers"][0]["classes"])`.